# Checking the existance of file with and without READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission

Tags: java, android

Let say that I have the simple code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        String sdCardPath = sdCard.getAbsolutePath();
        String parentPath = sdCardPath + File.separator + "parent";
        String childPath = parentPath + File.separator + "child";
        File parent = new File(parentPath);
        File child = new File(childPath);
        if (parent.exists()) {
            Log.d("LOG", "Parent folder exists");
        } else {
            Log.d("LOG", "Parent folder doesn't exist");
        }
        if (child.exists()) {
            Log.d("LOG", "Child folder exists");
        } else {
            Log.d("LOG", "Child folder doesn't exist");
        }

    }
}
```

On the other hand, I had created 2 folders `parent` and `child` at: `<sdcard_root>/parent` and `<sdcard_root>/parent/child` for checking.

When the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is **not** used in the manifest file, the result was: Parent folder **exists** and Child folder **doesn't exist**. When I add that permission in manifest file, the result was, as we might expected, both folder exist.

What make me confused here is that we can still detect that the `parent` folder, which is located at the root of sdcard, is exist even without using READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission, but we can't do this for the `child` folder. Why?

IMO, when not using read permission, the checking results should be: both parent and child folder don't exist. Why the files/folders which are located at root of external storage directory are treated differently? This seems to be an exception in my point of view. Finally, are there any similar exceptions that we should know when working with permissions in Android?

Thanks.

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: That does sound slightly odd, but keep in mind that you really shouldn't depend on READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE being enforced *at all* yet, as it's a relatively new addition to the platform that on most devices in the field today would only be active if explicitly turned on in developer settings (or in many, not at all). Instead of a practical test, can you query the package manager for your permissions, and restrict your behavior to what that indicates the platform is *supposed* to offer you?

Comment: @greenapps Checked on Lg and Samsung devices running Kitkat 4.4.2

Comment: Kitkat is peculiar. With File.canWrite() it tells that a directory is writable but when i try to copy a file i get an EACCESS permission denied.